# App installed from the App Store behaves differently with upscaling on larger iPhones than when installed through Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, ios8

I've just found out that one of my apps lags horribly, up to the point where it is virtually unusable on an iPhone 6 Plus - previous generation iPhones are working fine. Now this is where it gets interesting: When I install this app (same build, nothin) from Xcode on this same iPhone 6 Plus, everything works as expected, no lag whatsoever. I've tried both build configurations, Debug & Release and both work as expected.

So my question is, why would my app behave differently when installed from the App Store and how could I reproduce this problem through Xcode?

Comment: I have similar problem, did you find why it behaved differently when built for app store / add hoc?

Comment: It has to do with build configurations. My answer to this one still holds though, just install the exported ipa through iTunes to get the exact same experience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I at least found a way to reproduce the bug. To get the exact same experience a user gets from installing your app from the App Store, export your archive to an .ipa using an Ad Hoc distribution certificate and then install this .ipa through iTunes.

In conclusion, I believe this is a result of upscaling old apps on newer iPhones (6 & 6 Plus) which apparently doesn't always work as it should.